# white screen in right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the screen which is white on the side, I scroll to the right and there is a white screen which appears I would like to know how to remove it. I don't understand where in the `code` there is the problem

https://jsfiddle.net/y3j01hbt/

here is the whole code, you can see I can scroll right and there is a white screen. How can I remove this white screen? I can't understand where the error is, maybe from the aos library or I don't know, I tried a lot of things but I can't understand what it is

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also, you've violated site rules by posting your fiddle link as code. You _must_ put code here.  See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off horizontal scrolling by setting the `overflow-x` property to `hidden` on your html/body.

```
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT**

The horizontal scrolling you experience comes from your AOS styling/script. When you replace all instances of `data-aos="fade-left"` and `data-aos="fade-right"` with `data-aos="fade"`, you will see your problem has disappeared. You **will** need to use overflow hidden when using the left/right AOS animations.

Comment: Doing this masks layout problems. I don't recommend it.

Comment: This doesn't work, i have try. But thanks for try to help

Comment: Hiding overflow on your html/body should work, please try it in your fiddle. Also, please check my edited answer about the use of AOS.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is caused by the fade-left-aos-animation under section "À PROPOS" (scrollbar dissapears when it enters the screen).

This is most likely due to a bug in the aos-library.

If using another Version doesn't solve your problem you can just add a quick and dirty fix to the parent-container via overflow:hidden.

I added the following Code to your fiddle to fix it:

```
#scrollspyHeading6{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

[New Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfjmvks3/)

Comment: work in jsfiddle but not in host, there can see result : https://testportfolio111.000webhostapp.com/